# How to customize server response with jquery file upload from json

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I working on file upload feature on Ruby on Rails using this [jQuery file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/), I used this [example](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) to accomplish the task. the problem here is that as appeared in the example the response in create action with a json object so the uploaded content can be listed

```
render json: [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload
```

but I want to response with a different action after the image is uploded like format.js or .html, so How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The JS where the JSON is rendered should be changed from `$.getJSON` to `$.getScript`

Then, in your controller, drop the `render :json` you have and put something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {}
  format.js   {}
end
```

You should have a view that matches the corresponded format (my_view.js.erb or my_view.html.erb). Then put the code you want there.